# converting R code snippet to use the Matrix package?

Tags: math, r, matrix, sparse-matrix

I am not sure there are any R users out there, but just in case:

I am a novice at R and was kindly "handed down" the following R code snippet:

```
Beta <- exp(as.matrix(read.table('beta.transpose')))
WordFreq <- read.table('freq-matrix')
WordProbs <- WordFreq$V1 / sum(WordFreq)

infile <- file('freq-matrix')
outfile <- file('doc_topic_prob_matrix', 'w')

open(infile)
open(outfile)

for (i in 1:93049) {
  vec <- t(scan(infile, nlines=1))
  topics <- (vec/WordProbs) %*% Beta
  write.table(topics, outfile, append=T, row.names=F, col.names=F)
  }
```

When I tried running this on my dataset, the system thrashed and swapped like crazy. Now I realize that has a simple reason: the file freq-matrix holds a large (22GB) matrix and I was trying to read it into memory.

I have been told to use the [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/Matrix.pdf) package, because freq-matrix has many, many zeros all over the place and it handles such cases well. Will that help? If so, any hints on how to change this code would be most welcome. I have no R experience and just started reading through the introduction PDF available on the site.

Many thanks

~l

Comment: If possible, you should change whatever created freq-matrix to use a sparser representation.  Check out, for example, the format used by Blei's LDA-C package.

Comment: @Jonathan: you are here, too : ). Thank you for helping me out. (I'm only used to SAS and smaller datasets.) This giant was spitted out by python code I naively wrote. 

I am going through the Matrix package manual, but cannot understand how to build a sparse matrix **without already having done a read.table() on the 22GB file**. The Matrix constructor (p73 of the manual) takes as its arg the very matrix I want to make sparse! Of course, I cannot even get to that point because my machine blows up once I do that read.table().

Comment: Ideally you wouldn't be writing a 22 gb file in the first place =).  But if you really want to work with that file, you'll have to bypass read.table and write some functions yourself to read a few lines at a time and append each chunk to the sparse matrix.

Comment: Jonathan, many thanks. Promise I won't do the 22G thing again. : ) It was my first time. The Matrix constructor does not let me create a sparse matrix with the right dimensions; it complains about 'too many elements specified'. I tried m <- Matrix(NA,nrow=930000,ncol=143000, byrow=TRUE,dimnames=NULL,sparse=TRUE). [The frequency matrix (words over documents) is 90000K x 143K.]

Comment: Ok, success. (This comments thread has become something of a blog for my crash-course in R and large datasets. : ) ). If I create the matrix with 0 as the default value (rather than the default NA), I can create a giant matrix alright.
Now off to see how to fill it in. Again thanks for all your help. : )

Comment: Leave out the NA.  The sparse value is always 0, so if you set it to NA, you lose the sparsity.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion might be completely off, because you don't give enough details about the contents of your files, and I had to guess from the code. Anyway, here it goes.

You don't state it, but I would assume that your code crashes on the second line, when you read in the big matrix. The loop reads the lines one-at-a-time, and should not crash. The only reason you need that big matrix is to calculate the WordProbs vector. So why don't you rewrite that part using the same looping using `scan`? In fact, you could probably don't even need to store the `WordProbs` vector, just `sum(WordFreq)` - you can get that using an initial run through hte file. Then rewrite the formula within the loop to calculate the current `WordProb`.

Answer (score 0):

Belated answer, but I'd recommend reading the data into a memory mapped file, using the `bigmemory` package.  After that, I'd look for the non-zero entries, which can then be represented as a 3 column matrix: (ix_row, ix_col, value).  This is called a coordinate object list (COO), though the name is unimportant.  From there, `Matrix` supports the creation of sparse matrices (via `sparseMatrix`).  After you get the COO, you're pretty much set - conversion to and from the sparse matrix format is reasonably fast.  Multiplying the matrix by `Beta` should be reasonably fast.  If you need even greater speed, you could use an optimized BLAS library, but that opens up more questions.  :)